# Django Rest Framework hyperlinked serializer for a model with a property pointing to one specific related object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, what's the appropriate way to write a hyperlinked serializer for a model that has a property that points to a reverse related object or None?

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    a_name = models.CharField()

    @property
    def current_another_model(self):
        # Just an example, could be whatever code that returns an instance
        # of ``AnotherModel`` that is related to this instance of ``AModel``
        try:
            return self.another_model_set.objects.get(blah=7)
        except AnotherModel.DoesNotExist:
            return

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    blah = models.IntegerField()
    our_model = models.ForeignKey(AModel)
```

How do we write a serializer for AModel that contains the url (or `null`, of course) for the property `current_another_model`?

I've tried this  (I have a working `AnotherModel` serializer and view):

```
class AModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    current_another_model = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, view_name='another-model-detail', allow_null=True)
```

That gets me this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "another-model-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Answer (score -1):

Define AnotherModel serializer and define that dependency within AModelSerializer, also add class Meta in your AModelSerializer.

```
class AModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current_another_model = AnotherModelSerializer(allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ('current_another_model',)
```

That code should do the trick for you.

Another way is stick to the official [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#api-reference) while defining related serializers.

**Update:** Found quite similar question [Django Rest Framework - Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using)
 which is solved.

Comment: Almost.  This nests the serialized relation, whereas what I'm looking for is the hyperlink.

Comment: As for your update:  As I mention in the question detail, I do have a working serializer and view for the related object so the accepted answer on that question is not applicable.