# Django multiple pks in url

Tags: python, regex, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to build an API using the Django Rest Framework. Currently I want to be able to have multiple pks in a single url, but when I try I get an error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>   "^video/(?P[0-9]+)/quiz/(?P[0-9]+)/list/$" is not a valid
>   regular expression: redefinition of group name 'pk' as group 2; was
>   group 1 at position 31

Here are my URLS:

```
url(r'^video/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/quiz/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/list/$',
        views.QuizList.as_view(),
        name='quizzes-list'),
url(r'^video/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/quiz/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/detail/$',
        views.QuizDetail.as_view(),
        name='quizzes-detail'),
```

I am going to have multiple quizzes for a video and want to be able to reach them through a certain pk in my url.

Is there a simple method to do this or am missing the proper way to do this?

Thank you

Edit* Here are my views:

```
class VideoList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer


class VideoDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer


# quiz
class QuizList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Quizzes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer


class QuizDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Quizzes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
```

Updated urls:

```
    ###
    # Quiz urls
    ###

    url(r'^video/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/quiz/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/list/$',
        views.QuizList.as_view(),
        name='quizzes-list'),
    url(r'^video/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/quiz/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/detail/$',
        views.QuizDetail.as_view(),
        name='quizzes-detail'),
```

Updated views:

```
class QuizList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Quizzes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk1 = kwargs.get('pk1', None)
        pk2 = kwargs.get('pk2', None)
        print(pk1)
        print(pk2)
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

New Error:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "quizzes-list". You may have failed to include the related model in
>   your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

Answer (score 6):

You must give a unique name for the Named capturing group.

```
url(r'^video/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/quiz/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/list/$',
    views.QuizList.as_view(),
    name='quizzes-list'),
```

Access the corresponding `pk*` values in the view through,

```
pk1 = kwargs.get('pk1', None)
pk2 = kwargs.get('pk2', None)
```

ex:

```
# quiz
class QuizList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Quizzes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk1 = kwargs.get('pk1', None)
        pk2 = kwargs.get('pk2', None)
        print pk1
        print pk2
        return super(QuizList, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm still not understanding. I'm new to this. I posted my views. How would I implement the corresponding pk* to them?

Comment: I updated everything, but am now getting a new error which I posted above. I'm confused about the error because 'quizzes-list' is listed in the url name and I have no lookup_field. Any direction? Appreciate all the help.

Comment: @Ryan113 take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using