# ImproperlyConfigured Django API View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am facing an Odd problem in django.
It throws me a message that `ImproperlyConfigured`

below is my `Views.py`

```
class ArticleListCreateGet(ListAPIView, CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializers
```

and below is my `serializers.py`

```
class ArticleSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['author', 'title', 'body', 'category']
```

and below is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this my `urls.py`

```
url('^api/v1/article$', views.ArticleListCreateGet.as_view(), name='articleGetAndPost')
```

I guess my everything is ok but when i hit this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/article
```

It throws me this error message

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /api/v1/article

Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "author-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/article
Django Version:     2.2.and bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

How can get rid of this problem?

Comment: can you add ***complete `urls.py`***?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using) can help you out.