# Issues with HyperlinkedModelSerializer with recursive model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## Overview

I'm setting up a new Django application with Django REST Framework (DRF), and this is my first time using the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` for the API endpoint.

I've overridden the `get_queryset()` method on the ModelViewSet, so I've also the `basename` argument to the application router and explicitly defined the `url` attribute in the serializer as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43816995/3443946). This fixed issues that I was having with the model's own `url` attribute.

However, I'm getting the following error message when trying to serialize a ForeignKey field of the same class as the parent model. It fails with the following message:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "employee-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

Is there something special in the serializer I need to do to support using recursive model relationships like this?

---

## Example code

```py
# app/models.py

from django.db import models

class AbstractBase(models.Model):
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Employee(AbstractBase):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
  manager = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='direct_reports',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
  ...

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

```py
# app/views.py

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

from app import models
from app import serializers

# pagination defaults
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
  page_size = 25
  page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
  max_page_size = 1000

class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
  serializer_class = serializers.EmployeeSerializer
  http_method_names = ['options', 'get']

  def get_queryset(self):
    params = self.request.query_params
    queryset = models.Employee.objects.all()

    # apply url query filters...

    return queryset
```

```py
# app/serializers.py

from app import models
from rest_framework import serializers

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    read_only=True, view_name='employees-detail')
  manager = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    read_only=True, view_name='employees-detail')

  class Meta:
    model = models.Employee
    fields = ('url', 'name', 'manager')
```

```py
# project/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^api/', include('app.urls')),
]
```

```py
# app/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers

from app import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'employees', views.EmployeeViewSet, basename='employees')

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this worked, but changing the inherited serializer from `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` to `serializers.ModelSerializer` and removing the overridden `url` fixed things perfectly.

New serializer looks like this:

```py
# app/serializers.py

from app import models
from rest_framework import serializers

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  manager = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    read_only=True, view_name='employees-detail')

  class Meta:
    model = models.Employee
    fields = ('url', 'name', 'manager')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is using `HyperlinkedRelatedField` instead of `HyperlinkedIdentityField`. `HyperlinkedRelatedField` is for relations to other models. In this case, the link is to the model itself so use `HyperlinkedIdentityField` instead