# how to make drf HyperlinkedModelSerializer elegantly work with app_name?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using drf in django project

```py
# project/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('drf/', include('api.urls')),
    ...
]
```

in a dedicated app which I namespaced via ***app_name*** as following:

```py
# api/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

app_name = 'drf'

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('segments', views.SegmentViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

```py
# api/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from segment.models import Segment

class SegmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ['id', 'url', 'name']
```

```py
# api/views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import SegmentSerializer
from segment.models import Segment

class SegmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Segment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SegmentSerializer
```

calling endpoint ***/drf/segments/*** results in the following error:

```sh
ImproperlyConfigured at /drf/segments/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "segment-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/drf/segments/
Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Executable: /Users/udos/.virtualenvs/ts/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.4
.
.
.
```

to "fix" this, I have to add the following code to the serializer:

```
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name='drf:segment-detail',
)
```

resulting in:

```py
# api/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from segment.models import Segment

class SegmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='drf:segment-detail',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ['id', 'url', 'name']
```

I have to do this for all entities (which I would like to avoid).

is there a way to handle this without using the extra code? some magic method/attribute to call/set?

Comment: Can you try to explicily pass the namespace: `path('', include(router.urls, namespace='drf'))` ?

Comment: adding that to `api/urls.py` results in error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.`

Comment: Don't drop the `app_name`.

Comment: :| I didn't. I used `path('', include(router.urls, namespace=app_name))`

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @bwdm, unfortunately I did not find a way around this. my code still looks the same