# Django Rest Framework - ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using), but I do not have namespaces or base-names, so none of the solutions in that question have worked.

I have 2 models:
Organisation
Student

A student can belong to an organisation.

When I retrieve an organisation, I want a child object in the returned JSON that lists the 'related' students as hyperlinked urls (as per HATEOS).

**models.py**

```
class Organisation(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Student(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  organisation = models.ForeignKey(to=Organisation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True, related_name='students')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class OrganisationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  students = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, view_name='student-detail', lookup_url_kwarg='organisation_id')

  class Meta:
    model = Organisation
    fields = ('id', 'name','students')

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import OrganisationViewSet, StudentViewSet

from django.conf.urls import url

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api/v1/organisations', OrganisationViewSet)
router.register(r'api/v1/students', StudentViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Organisation, Student
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializers import OrganisationSerializer, StudentSerializer

# Organisation Viewset
class OrganisationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Organisation.objects.all()
  serializer_class = OrganisationSerializer
  permission_classes = [
    permissions.AllowAny
  ]

# Student Viewset
class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Student.objects.all()
  serializer_class = StudentSerializer
  permission_classes = [
    permissions.AllowAny
  ]
```

So this should work as this is pretty boiler-plate code. Or maybe I don't understand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the URL configuration and **`StudentViewSet`** , you don't have to provide the **`lookup_url_kwarg`** value in the **`HyperlinkedRelatedField`**. So, your serializer will become as,

```
class OrganisationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,
                                                   read_only=True,
                                                   view_name='student-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Organisation
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'students')
```